# Most common methods to play audio and video for app users fast and efficiently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, audio, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I've seen several methods and opinions -- including streaming the media (HLS, RTSP), or just using regular mp3, AAC, mp4, etc. What is the most common method for playing audio and video for users from a database? (Eg. the user taps a play button and media plays.) Does the size of the file (length of the media) affect this choice? What is considered standard practice?

For context, I'm designing an app with Flutter using either AWS or firebase as a backend that will allow users to listen to audio (as short as 5 min, as long as 20) and eventually watch videos. Looking for a method that is efficient in bandwidth as well as fast for the end user.

Audio is my primary objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HLS streaming is the de facto approach for delivering video - especially if over 5 minutes. You'll have to encode different sizes/bitrates for different sized screens. The good thing is this will reduce bandwidth for smaller screens.

For playback, Streaming is not natively supported in the browser, you'll need a JS player to play back the video (video.js is a good one).

There are APIs and services that will encode your videos, host them, and provide you with a player to playback the video (upload the video, and get the playback url). I work for [api.video](https://api.video) but there is also [Mux](https://mux.com) and others that can save you a lot of headache in building your app.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow,

From what I have seen, the big audio platforms use streaming.

Check this flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

It is very easy to implemente in your code. You can use to play long audio files/streams from the internet.

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);

  play() async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);
    if (result == 1) {
      // success
    }
  }
```

About playing video, I don't have any experience, I can't give any opinion.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I appreciate the advice